Pseudosphere Involute space curve
A hyper pseudosphere of const negative Gauss curvature $-1/a^2$ has a maximum cusp radius  $r_o$  and a minimum  radius of base circle $r_b$ at its neck.
An involute is drawn by unwinding/sweeping a string from the $r_b$ circle keeping the string taut while its end P traces out the involute space curve C.
Show that

C has constant geodesic curvature $ 1/a, $
Arc length of the  involute traced out by P from  base circle  to cuspidal equator is $\dfrac{a^2}{r_b}.$


To compare with standard 2D involute of a circle we have the constant base circle radius $r_{b}= r \cos \psi =OT $:

However the geometry in general 3D situation has not much to compare, a constant radius of curvature of the involute is counter-intuitive... ( except that the Beltrami- Enneper theorem gives geodesic torsion $\tau_g$ of asymptotic lines constant $1/a$ and here we have geodesic curvature $\kappa_g$ of involutes as the same $1/a$ ).
I request your help to find any literature where the 3D involute references is already available. I had derived the above result.
